# C# Console application decode urlencoded string

Tags: c#, youtube

I am using youtoube service to get video information(
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=VideoId),
It return response in form of :application/x-www-form-urlencoded
I want to decode it in C# console application I have tried :System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode
but it returns same string.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: after decoding still I getting %25 and %26 and other decoded values in string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString on the result of UrlDecode, and you'll get a NameValueCollection that'll let you access the decoded data.

```
string query = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input);
NameValueCollection result = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);

foreach (var key in result.AllKeys)
{
    var value = result[key];
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, value);
}
```